# MethodNotAllowedHttpException Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, exception, routes

i'm starting now with Laravel

i get an MethodNotAllowedHttpException while trying to add a new user from an authenticated one.

this is the input form (add.blade.php)

```
 <form method="POST" action="{{ action('Backend\UserController@store') }}">

  {{csrf_field()}}


  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
    <input id="first_name" type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" value="{{ old('first_name') }}" placeholder="Your Name" required>
    <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"> -->
  </div>

   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
    <input id="last_name" type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" value="{{ old('first_name') }}" placeholder="Your Surname" required>
    <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"> -->
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">E-Mail:</label>
    <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="Your Email" required>
    <!--<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">-->
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Your Password" required>
    <!--<input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">-->
  </div>


  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
  </div>

  @include ('layouts.errors')

</form>
```

this is the user controller (UserController.php), please check the store method

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class UserController extends Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth');

    }

    public function getIndex() {
        $users = User::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
        return view('backend.user.list', compact('users'));
    }

    public function getAdd() {
        // schermata di aggiunta del nuovo autore
        return view('backend.user.add');
    }

    public function store(Request $request) {
        // elaborazione dei dati ed effettiva aggiunta dell'autore

        $this->validate(request(), [

            'first_name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed',

        ]);

        //Create and Save the Users
        $first_name = $request->first_name;
        $last_name = $request->last_name;
        $email = $request->email;
        $password = $request->password;
        $slug = Str::slug($first_name . $last_name);

        $user = User::create([
            'first_name' => $first_name,
            'last_name' => $last_name,
            'email' => $email,
            'slug' => $slug,
            'password' => bcrypt($password),

        ]);

        return redirect('backend/indexuser');

    }

    public function getDelete($userId, Request $request) {
        $userToDelete = User::find($userId);
        $userToDelete->delete();
        //$userId->delete();

        $request->session()->flash('success_message', 'User Deleted');
        return redirect('backend/indexuser');
    }
}
```

this is the routes (web.php)

```
Route::get('backend/indexuser', 'Backend\UserController@getIndex');
Route::get('backend/adduser', 'Backend\UserController@getAdd');
Route::post('backend/adduser', 'Backend\UserController@store');
Route::get('backend/indexuser/delete/{id}', 'Backend\UserController@getDelete');
```

After the user registration  i'm redirected to http://192.168.33.10/myBlog/public/logout with the  MethodNotAllowedHttpException screen

this is the php artisan route:list

```
+--------+----------+-------------------------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                           | Name | Action                                                     | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+-------------------------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                             |      | App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController@getIndex           | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user                      |      | Closure                                                    | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD | articolo/{slug}               |      | App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController@getArticolo        | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | autore/{slug}                 |      | App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController@getAutore          | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | backend/adduser               |      | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\UserController@getAdd         | web,auth     |
|        | POST     | backend/adduser               |      | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\UserController@store          | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD | backend/indexuser             |      | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\UserController@getIndex       | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD | backend/indexuser/delete/{id} |      | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\UserController@getDelete      | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD | categoria/{slug}              |      | App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController@getCategoria       | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | dashboard                     |      | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\SessionsController@getIndex   | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD | login                         | home | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\SessionsController@create     | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | login                         |      | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\SessionsController@store      | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | logout                        |      | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\SessionsController@destroy    | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD | register                      |      | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\RegistrationController@create | web          |
|        | POST     | register                      |      | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\RegistrationController@store  | web
```

what's wrong?
Thanks

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ UPDATE 1 //////////////////////////

checked my rendered HTML.

```
 <form method="POST" action="http://192.168.33.10/myBlog/public/backend/adduser">

          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="cWbRF1A7UWEzPWqtmVhVocbzQdkwKgc8dABne28v">


          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
            <input id="first_name" type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" value="" placeholder="Your Name" required>
            <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"> -->
          </div>
```

This is my RedirectIfAuthenticated.php in middleware folder

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated {
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null) {
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {

        return redirect('dashboard');

    }

    return $next($request);
  }
}
```

This is unauthenticated method in Handler.php

```
        protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception) {
            if ($request->expectsJson()) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
            }

            //return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
            //redirect se l'utente prova ad accedere da guest, reindirizzo a login
            return redirect()->home();
        }
    }
```

In the /storage/logs/laravel.log i can't find anything interesting in the end,
these are the last rows

```
#47 /var/www/public/myBlog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#48 /var/www/public/myBlog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#49 /var/www/public/myBlog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#50 /var/www/public/myBlog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#51 /var/www/public/myBlog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#52 /var/www/public/myBlog/public/index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#53 {main}
```

\\\\\\\\ UPDATE 2 //////////////////////////

[Log From storage/logs/laravel.log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3cWQZHdgz9FUnNDT1Ayd2I4a2c)

Comment: data entry done in table?

Comment: Are you sure you are posting to `/backend/adduser` uri? I think your `action('Backend\UserController@store` snippet didn't return expected uri.

Comment: Have you added slug field to $fillable array in User model?

Comment: @KooroshPasokhi yes i have: protected $fillable = [
  'first_name', 'last_name', 'slug', 'email', 'password',
 ];

Comment: @piotr after filling the form with first name, last name, email and password, no user was created and i've been redirected to public/logout and i don't know why.

Comment: @B.Desai name: Bob, last name: Red, email: bobred@red.com, password: mypassword

Comment: Post some last errors from your log. You posted few lines od one error. But I  need at least one full error trace. What is your `RedirectResponse` ?

Comment: Hello @piotr , i changed RedirectResponse with return redirect('dashboard'); I pasted the entire log in a file linked under the "Update 2" section. Thanks

Comment: i'm close to solve the issue. A GET is called for the "logout" (a link on top menu allowing users to destroy the session via auth()->logout();), if i comment the logout route Route::get('logout', 'Backend\SessionsController@destroy'); and from the master blade i can finally create USER doing my action action('Backend\UserController@store')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched the logout ruote from Get to Post, then i've moved the form action from the Navbar (master layout page) to the Dashboard page, and the problem is solved now

```
    <p>Benvenuto {{ Auth::user()->first_name }} ! Scegli cosa vuoi fare usando il menu qui in alto.</p>

    <form action="{{ action('Backend\SessionsController@destroy') }}" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Log Out</button>
            </div>
    </form>

@endsection
```

Something went wrong in the master layout blade. When i tried to create a new user with the 'Backend\UserController@store' action the logout action was called as well.
I cannot figure it out well, but now i solved it replacing the "navbar logout" with a button in dashboard page.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Why not just using the url() function?

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('backend/adduser') }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

**First:**
check your rendered HTML. I think there is somenthing weird rendered in `action` part of your form.

**if problem persist**
check if you have untouched `auth` middleware

**if problem still persist**
check your logs (`/storage/logs/laravel.log`) and share it with us.

Comment: Hello @piotr Thanks in advance. Please, check the update 1 in the main post.